# Speed up reading in a compressed bz2 file ('rb' mode)

Tags: python, compression, buffering, bz2

I have a BZ2 file of more than 10GB. I'd like to read it without decompressing it into a temporary file (it would be more than 50GB).

With this method:

```
import bz2, time
t0 = time.time()
time.sleep(0.001) # to avoid / by 0
with bz2.open("F:\test.bz2", 'rb') as f:
    for i, l in enumerate(f):
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            print('%i lines/sec' % (i/(time.time() - t0)))
```

I can only read ~ 250k lines per second. On a similar file, first *decompressed*, I get ~ 3M lines per second, i.e. a x10 factor:

```
with open("F:\test.txt", 'rb') as f:
```

I think it's not only due to the intrinsic decompression CPU time (because the total time of decompression into a temp file + the reading as uncompressed file is much smaller than the method described here), but maybe a lack of buffering, or other reasons. Are there other faster Python implementations of `bz2.open`?

**How to speed up the reading of a BZ2 file, in binary mode, and loop over "lines"?** (separated by `\n`)

Note: currently `time to decompress test.bz2 into test.tmp + time to iterate over lines of test.tmp` is far smaller than `time to iterate over lines of bz2.open('test.bz2')`, and this probably should not be the case.

Linked topic: https://discuss.python.org/t/non-optimal-bz2-reading-speed/6869

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BZ2Decompressor` to deal with huge files. It decompresses blocks of data incrementally, just out of the box:

```
t0 = time.time()
time.sleep(0.000001)
with open('temp.bz2', 'rb') as fi:
    decomp = bz2.BZ2Decompressor()
    residue = b''
    total_lines = 0
    for data in iter(lambda: fi.read(100 * 1024), b''):
        raw = residue + decomp.decompress(data) # process the raw data and  concatenate residual of the previous block to the beginning of the current raw data block
        residue = b''
        # process_data(current_block) => do the processing of the current data block
        current_block = raw.split(b'\n')
        if raw[-1] != b'\n':
            residue = current_block.pop() # last line could be incomplete
        total_lines += len(current_block)
        print('%i lines/sec' % (total_lines / (time.time() - t0)))
    # process_data(residue) => now finish processing the last line
    total_lines += 1
    print('Final: %i lines/sec' % (total_lines / (time.time() - t0)))
```

Here I read a chunk of binary file, feed it into a decompressor and receive a chunk of decompressed data. Be aware, the decompressed data chunks have to be concatenated to restore the original data. This is why last entry needs special treatment.

In my experiments it runs a little faster then your solution with `io.BytesIO()`. `bz2` is known to be slow, so if it bothers you consider migration to `snappy` or `zstandard`.

Regarding the time it takes to process `bz2` in Python. It might be fastest to decompress the file into temporary one using Linux utility and then process a normal text file. Otherwise you will be dependent on Python's implementation of `bz2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you sure `bz2.open()` decompresses into a temp file? I don't think so: I haven't found this in the doc, and I don't see the temp file anywhere (but I might be wrong!) Your method works well (850k lines/sec in my tests vs. 700k lines/sec with my latest methods), but the price to pay is to be able to load the whole decompressed file in memory, in your `data`, `temp` objects. This is not possible for me with 50 GB files ;)

Comment: 1) re temp file this is what I understood from the docs in the Internet. Today I tried to check,  it is not the case anymore. 2) re block processing. I'm sorry for not making it clear enough, that the method allows processing of the huge files. Please see updated version.

Comment: Great, I'll test your new version! PS: you can maybe update your first paragraph about "temporary file".

Comment: You have a nice solution here @igrinis, you may want to post it here (core python developers discussion): https://discuss.python.org/t/non-optimal-bz2-reading-speed/6869

Answer (score 0):

This method already gives a x2 improvement over native `bz2.open`.

```
import bz2, time, io

def chunked_readlines(f):
    s = io.BytesIO()
    while True:
        buf = f.read(1024*1024)
        if not buf:
            return s.getvalue()
        s.write(buf)
        s.seek(0)
        L = s.readlines()
        yield from L[:-1]
        s = io.BytesIO()
        s.write(L[-1])  # very important: the last line read in the 1 MB chunk might be
                        # incomplete, so we keep it to be processed in the next iteration
                        # TODO: check if this is ok if f.read() stopped in the middle of a \r\n?

t0 = time.time()
i = 0
with bz2.open("D:\test.bz2", 'rb') as f:
    for l in chunked_readlines(f):       # 500k lines per second
    # for l in f:                        # 250k lines per second
        i += 1
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            print('%i lines/sec' % (i/(time.time() - t0)))
```

It is probably possible to do even better.

We could have a x4 improvement if we could use `s` as a a simple `bytes` object instead of a `io.BytesIO`. But unfortunately in this case, `splitlines()` does not behave as expected: [splitlines() and iterating over an opened file give different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65765343/splitlines-and-iterating-over-an-opened-file-give-different-results).