# splitlines() and iterating over an opened file give different results

Tags: python, split, end-of-line

I have files with sometimes weird end-of-lines characters like `\r\r\n`. With this, it works like I want:

```
with open('test.txt', 'wb') as f:  # simulate a file with weird end-of-lines
    f.write(b'abc\r\r\ndef')
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for l in f:
        print(l)
# b'abc\r\r\n'         
# b'def'
```

I want to able to get the same result *from a string*. I thought about `splitlines` but it does not give the same result:

```
print(b'abc\r\r\ndef'.splitlines())
# [b'abc', b'', b'def']
```

Even with `keepends=True`, it's not the same result.

**Question: how to have the same behaviour than `for l in f` with `splitlines()`?**

Linked: [Changing str.splitlines to match file readlines](https://discuss.python.org/t/changing-str-splitlines-to-match-file-readlines/174) and https://bugs.python.org/issue22232

Note: I don't want to put everything in a `BytesIO` or `StringIO`, because it does a x0.5 speed performance (already benchmarked); I want to keep a simple string. So it's not a duplicate of [How do I wrap a string in a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python).

Comment: are you looking for `splitlines()` behaviour with the `for l in f`? the former split the lines on much more cases, whlie the latter split on `\n`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I wrap a string in a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141449/how-do-i-wrap-a-string-in-a-file-in-python)

Comment: No @mkrieger1, I don't want to put everything in a BytesIO or StringIO, because it does a x0.5  speed performance (already benchmarked). I want to keep a simple string.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, it's now fixed in the edit.

Comment: If you are reading the strings from files anyway, why don't you use the `for l in f` interface, then?

Comment: For a complex reason, a little bit out of topic here, but to be precise, because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763959/speed-up-reading-in-a-compressed-bz2-file-rb-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just split it:

```
input = b'\nabc\r\r\r\nd\ref\nghi\r\njkl'
result = input.split(b'\n') 
print(result)

[b'', b'abc\r\r\r', b'd\ref', b'ghi\r', b'jkl']
```

You will loose the trailing `\n` that can be added later to every line, if you really need them. On the last line there is a need to check if it is really needed. Like

```
fixed = [bstr + b'\n' for bstr in result]
if input[-1] != b'\n':
    fixed[-1] = fixed[-1][:-1]
print(fixed)

[b'\n', b'abc\r\r\r\n', b'd\ref\n', b'ghi\r\n', b'jkl']
```

Another variant with a generator. This way it will be memory savvy on the huge files and the syntax will be similar to the original `for l in bin_split(input)` :

```
def bin_split(input_str):
    start = 0
    while start>=0 :
        found = input_str.find(b'\n', start) + 1
        if 0 < found < len(input_str):
            yield input_str[start : found]
            start = found
        else:
            yield input_str[start:]
            break
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the better. How couldn't I think about this! It seems to perfectly work, even with weird end-of-lines like `\r\r\r\n`, as well as `\r\n` or `\n`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways to do this, but none are especially fast.

If you want to keep the line endings, you might try the `re` module:

```
lines = re.findall(r'[\r\n]+|[^\r\n]+[\r\n]*', text)
# or equivalently
line_split_regex = re.compile(r'[\r\n]+|[^\r\n]+[\r\n]*')
lines = line_split_regex.findall(text)
```

If you need the endings and the file is really big, you may want to iterate instead:

```
for r in re.finditer(r'[\r\n]+|[^\r\n]+[\r\n]*', text):
    line = r.group()
    # do stuff with line here
```

If you don't need the endings, then you can do it much more easily:

```
lines = list(filter(None, text.splitlines()))
```

You can omit the `list()` part if you just iterate over the results (or if using Python2):

```
for line in filter(None, text.splitlines()):
    pass # do stuff with line
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through like this:

```
text  = "b'abc\r\r\ndef'"

results = text.split('\r\r\n')

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a general solution, I don't want to hardcode `\r\r\n`. Each file I'm processing from different sources might use different end of lines.

Comment: How are you identifying the delimiter then? This should work with any delimiter

Comment: Some files have weird delimiters, some files might use some delimiters in the beginning then others. I don't have control on the source data I'm processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `for l in f:` solution:

The key to this is the `newline` argument on the `open` call. From the documentation:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Therefore, you should use `newline=''` when writing to suppress newline translation and then when reading use `newline='\n'`, which will work if all your lines terminate with 0 or more `'\r'` characters followed by a `'\n'` character:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write('abc\r\r\ndef')
with open('test.txt', 'r', newline='\n') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(repr(line))
```

Prints:

```
'abc\r\r\n'
'def'
```

**A *quasi-splitlines* solution:**

This strictly speaking not a `splitlines` solution since to be able to handle arbitrary line endings a regular expression version of `split` would have to be used capturing the line endings and then re-assembling the lines and their endings. So, instead this solution just uses a regular expression to break up the input text allowing line endings consisting of any number of `'\r'` characters followed by a `'\n'` character:

```
import re

input = '\nabc\r\r\ndef\nghi\r\njkl'

with open('test.txt', 'w', newline='') as f:
    f.write(input)
with open('test.txt', 'r', newline='') as f:
    text = f.read()
    lines = re.findall(r'[^\r\n]*\r*\n|[^\r\n]+$', text)
    for line in lines:
        print(repr(line))
```

Prints:

```
'\n'
'abc\r\r\n'
'def\n'
'ghi\r\n'
'jkl'
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VUCj6l/1/)